# Change calendar day back color

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to save a day data from calendar and change it color to red after click on it . so the saved on in database will be in red color and unsaved will be in green color .

The problem is when i choose multiple days just the last one will change to red the previous one will stuck in green color . 
The data is received  from sql correctly i show it in text box and all saved days is appear

```
int[] arr;
dynamic ad;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand c1 = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from app1", cn);

    int count = int.Parse(c1.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    cn.Close();
     arr = new int[count];
     DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
        ad  =(from a in db.app1s  select a.data).ToArray();

}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //id is int 

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into app1 values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "')", cn);
    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();

}


protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in ad)
    {
        if (int.Parse(item) == int.Parse(Calendar1.SelectedDate.Day.ToString()))
        {
            Calendar1.SelectedDayStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            Calendar1.SelectedDayStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            TextBox5.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Day.ToString();
        }
    }



}
```

I try to use array but same problem

```
int[] arr;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand c1 = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from apoyt1", cn);

    int count = int.Parse(c1.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    cn.Close();
     arr = new int[count + 1];

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        cn.Open();

        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("select data from apoyt1 where id='" + i + "'", cn);
        arr[i] = int.Parse(cm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

        cn.Close();

    }


}


protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //id is int 

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into apoyt1 values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "')", cn);
    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();

}






protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == int.Parse(Calendar1.SelectedDate.Day.ToString()))
        {
            Calendar1.SelectedDayStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        else {
            Calendar1.SelectedDayStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            TextBox5.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Day.ToString();
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: I think you're parsing the wrong elements. Calendar1.SelectedDay is Always the same one. So i think that you should parse the calendar days based on the dates you have on your array.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not doing the purpose that it should planed for, as well `Calendar1.SelectedDayStyle.BackColor` is always referring to same selected object.  so try the following:
1) create a list for days, as number of days are unknown.

```
 List<Int32> days;

      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {              
      }
```

2) Because of each time the page is reloading you need to store these days in a session.

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          days = (List<int>)Session["var"];
           if (days == null) days = new List<int>();
           days.Add(Calendar1.SelectedDate.Day);
           Session["var"] = days;
           ListBox1.Items.Clear();
              foreach (int d in days)
              {
                Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(new DateTime(Calendar1.SelectedDate.Year, Calendar1.SelectedDate.Month, d));
                Calendar1.SelectedDayStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                ListBox1.Items.Add(d.ToString());
           }

      }
```

3) i have uploaded a sample of code so you can check it [Here](http://www.computing.northampton.ac.uk/~14435651/Codes/WebApplication3.rar)